# Explanation of this prefix Sum Coding Challenge from Codility GenomicRangeQuery in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, algorithm

Could someone explain how this prefix sum calculation work as I am confused I mean I understand that it creates an array of Ints with the prefix-sums of the letters but I do not understand how? Could someone perhaps post a more naive logic or some explanation? Or perhaps a shorter version of that MAP function as it is all confusingly complicated.

[Link](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/5-prefix_sums/genomic_range_query/) to the challenge just in case someone would like to have a look at it

```
public func solution(_ S : inout String, _ P : inout [Int], _ Q : inout [Int]) -> [Int] {
//The mapping below needs the explanation
    var prefixSumA = S.map({ () -> (Character) -> Int in
        var s = 0; return {
            if $0 == "A" {
                return (s += 1, s).1
            }
            return s
        }
        }())//until here
    prefixSumA.insert(0, at: 0)
    var prefixSumC = S.map({ () -> (Character) -> Int in
        var s = 0; return {
            if $0 == "C" {
                return (s += 1, s).1
            }
            return s
        }
        }())
    prefixSumC.insert(0, at: 0)
    var prefixSumG = S.map({ () -> (Character) -> Int in
        var s = 0; return {
            if $0 == "G" {
                return (s += 1, s).1
            }
            return s
        }
        }())
    prefixSumG.insert(0, at: 0)


    let iterations = min(P.count, Q.count)

    var result = [Int]()

    for i in 0...iterations - 1 {
        let p = P[i]
        let q = Q[i] + 1
        if prefixSumA[q] - prefixSumA[p] > 0 {
            result.append(1)
        } else if prefixSumC[q] - prefixSumC[p] > 0 {
            result.append(2)
        } else if prefixSumG[q] - prefixSumG[p] > 0 {
            result.append(3)
        } else {
            result.append(4)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`prefixSumA` calculates the number of `A`s from the start to every given index. The same can be said about `prefixSumC`, and `prefixSumG`.

For example, if the string `S` is `"CAGCCTA"`, we'll have:

```
prefixSumA = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
prefixSumC = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
prefixSumG = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

(Notice the zero inserted at the beginning.)

---

This block of code:

```
var prefixSumA = S.map({ () -> (Character) -> Int in
    var s = 0; return {
        if $0 == "A" {
            return (s += 1, s).1
        }
        return s
    }
    }())
prefixSumA.insert(0, at: 0)
```

returns a closure that, if the character is `A`, would capture the current value of `s` (which is the last value in the array), increment it, end return it (`s`).

`return (s += 1, s).1` is a fancy way, that could be written as:

```
s += 1
return s
```

The whole block can be written more simply:

```
var prefixSumA = [0]
var countOfA = 0
prefixSumA += S.map { char in
    if char == "A" { countOfA += 1 }
    return countOfA
}
```

The same can be done for `prefixSumC` and `prefixSumG`.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this one and got 62%. Performance Tests Fails.

```
public func solution(_ S : inout String, _ P : inout [Int], _ Q : inout [Int]) -> [Int] {
// write your code in Swift 4.2.1 (Linux)

   var retArr = [Int]()
   var chrArr = [Character]()
   for chr in S {
       chrArr.append(chr)
   }


   for i in 0..<P.count {

       var minFactor = 4

       if P[i] - Q[i] == 0 {
           if chrArr[P[i]] == "A"{
               minFactor = 1
           }else if chrArr[P[i]] == "C"{
               minFactor = 2
           }else if chrArr[P[i]] == "G"{
               minFactor = 3
           }
       }else {
           for j in P[i]...Q[i] {

               if chrArr[j] == "A"{
                   minFactor = 1
                       break
               }else if chrArr[j] == "C"{
                       minFactor = 2
               }else if chrArr[j] == "G"{
                       if minFactor > 2 {
                           minFactor = 3
                           }
                   }
               }
       }

       retArr.append(minFactor)
   }

   return retArr
```

}