# Take into consideration Long Arrays/Strings

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying the challenges/Exercises of codility and I've come across a problem. When it tests Large Arrays/Strings my code always results in Timeout Errors. An example of this would be the following challenge:
*"GenomicRangeQuery"*

A non-empty zero-indexed string S is given. String S consists of N characters from the set of upper-case English letters A, C, G, T.

This string actually represents a DNA sequence, and the upper-case letters represent single nucleotides.

You are also given non-empty zero-indexed arrays P and Q consisting of M integers. These arrays represent queries about minimal nucleotides. We represent the letters of string S as integers 1, 2, 3, 4 in arrays P and Q, where A = 1, C = 2, G = 3, T = 4, and we assume that A < C < G < T.

Query K requires you to find the minimal nucleotide from the range (P[K], Q[K]), 0 ≤ P[i] ≤ Q[i] < N.

For example, consider string S = GACACCATA and arrays P, Q such that:

```
P[0] = 0    Q[0] = 8
P[1] = 0    Q[1] = 2
P[2] = 4    Q[2] = 5
P[3] = 7    Q[3] = 7
```

The minimal nucleotides from these ranges are as follows:

```
(0, 8) is A identified by 1,
(0, 2) is A identified by 1,
(4, 5) is C identified by 2,
(7, 7) is T identified by 4.
```

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int[] solution(String S, int[] P, int[] Q); }
```

that, given a non-empty zero-indexed string S consisting of N characters and two non-empty zero-indexed arrays P and Q consisting of M integers, returns an array consisting of M characters specifying the consecutive answers to all queries.

For example, given the string S = GACACCATA and arrays P, Q such that:

```
P[0] = 0    Q[0] = 8
P[1] = 0    Q[1] = 2
P[2] = 4    Q[2] = 5
P[3] = 7    Q[3] = 7
```

the function should return the values [1, 1, 2, 4], as explained above.

Assume that:

```
N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
M is an integer within the range [1..50,000];
each element of array P, Q is an integer within the range [0..N − 1];
P[i] ≤ Q[i];
string S consists only of upper-case English letters A, C, G, T.
```

Below is the code I've come up with but unfortunately always gives me the Timeout Error when going against Large Arrays/Strings.
If you have suggestions on how to improve or wipe out that error please don't hesitate! I'm always trying to think outside of the box and come up with solutions of my own but that error has been plaguing me for a while.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {
    public int[] solution(String S, int[] P, int[] Q) {
        // A impact = 1; C=2, G=3; T=4
        // S not empty
        // minimal impact
        String[] split;
        int[] stringToIntegers = new int[S.length()];
        int[] solution = new int[P.length];

        if(S.isEmpty()) return solution;
        if(P.length != Q.length) return solution;
        split = S.split("");

        for(int k=0;k<split.length;k++){
            switch(split[k]){
                case "A":
                    stringToIntegers[k] = 1;
                    break;
                case "C":
                    stringToIntegers[k] = 2;
                     break;
                case "G":
                    stringToIntegers[k] = 3;
                    break;
                case "T":
                    stringToIntegers[k] = 4;
                    break;
            }
        }
        for(int i =0; i<solution.length;i++){
                solution[i] = LowestValue(stringToIntegers, P[i], Q[i]);
        }
        return solution;
    }

    public int LowestValue(int[] stringToIntegers, int pValue, int qValue){
        int minimalImpact = 4;
        for(int j = pValue; j <= qValue; j++){
            if(stringToIntegers[j] < minimalImpact){
                minimalImpact = stringToIntegers[j];
            }
        }
        return minimalImpact;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into prefix-sums :). There is also a post of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552754/java-codility-training-genomic-range-query

Comment: Timeout Errors Put the full stack trace printout of the error from the error console into your post , it always helps in some way. Of time out are you doing that over a network or http?

Comment: On P and Q , how do you get numbers larger than 4 and also 0 zero. Are those site numbers representing sets of those assigned letters A C G T. ... and you want some type of precedence sorting rules. (possibly use java.text.RuleBasedCollator)

Comment: @SamuelMarchant you don't have numbers larger than 4 or lower than 0, A C G and T represent 1,2,3,4 respectively. The numbers on P and Q mean the position on the original Array! P={0,0,1} and Q={0,1,1} means that in the String S, you will need to get position 0 and go to position 0, then 0 and go to 1 and finally 1 and go to 1!

Comment: Take a look where you wrote ..."For example, consider string S = GACACCATA and arrays P, Q such that:"... below are array examples that have 7 and 5 , also , that String GACACCATA is 9 long but taking a look in some pdf's on nucleotide tests that stands to be as i said a vastly long string and any one character read from a file associated its RandomAccessFile seek() index (hence 2 byte char test to check symbol ISO) to understand where it was grabbed from after test. What is the 7 and 5 ? 1234 either as index or 1234 as value of the found index , why 7 and 5 as a value in the example P and Q.

Comment: And if you want to get between reading a section from file, to operating on the info with test, then save results, then move along, you can use threads rather than simply separate methods to clearly separate long periods of activity, replace method activity with threads. java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory , java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor , java.util.concurrent.Executors , take a look at the constructors and static methods to create pools and assign cores. Set of jobs threadpool , set of activities in each job inside job class subset of threads

Answer (score 1):

One simple optimization would be to short-circuit the innermost loop when you have found the value 1 (as you will not be able to find a lower value):

```
for(int j = pValue; j <= qValue; j++){
   if(stringToIntegers[j] < minimalImpact){
      minimalImpact = stringToIntegers[j];
      if(minimalImpact == 1)
         return 1;
   }
}
return minimalImpact;
```

Answer (score -1):

**HMMMMMMMM OH WOW MAN ... WOW ... a timeout you say ... WOW ....**
Did someone mention **D**eoxy **R**ibo **N**ucleic Acid?
i think the problem you have is more you may be using a large PC not a **"Super Cradle"**
**!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Do not use String/arrays unless there may be ISO character set *problems, then those should be char[] arrays*.
Get the String data to match and chew through it reading it from a file into a temporary handlable String[] array looping over it, such as a java.io.RandomAccessFile
com.nicephotog.tools.discfileifc Interface FileUnitisedByteRead may be useful
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IBbsBY9zWewKaq7hYnTzdI4M1XcVWELS/view?usp=sharing
*note randomacessfile can have its file length extended or created at size required.

First, setup your java program command line for
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

**-Xss1024k** (1mb is maximum under Linux or Win X64) this is your maximum **stack size memory reserved**, it is the most important because it will allow the variables and methods to shift the values and operations around in the registers.

Then the others used usually in the startup java command
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/JRPTG/memman.htm

-Xms

-Xmx

-XX:ErrorFile=filename

You cannot do that with a string that long, chew along it in pieces.
A regex would have the same memory problem.
You should also asses whether your data contains "2 byte" characters to match in the charset data that may need searching the extracted array section first before to find them and the array end last element whether it is suspected part of a 2 byte character.
This last scenario has array length and file read skip over single element problems to custom write into the code.

Check your loop rules of the conditions terminate properly. Precedence sorting can be expensive and unefficient at shuffling them into order too https://www.scribd.com/doc/44569594/avg-pdf.